# Removing AMP Pages from Magento

Tags: magento2, htaccess, google

Google AMP is a massive failure. I have seen my engagement and click rates all go down atleast 30% across all my sites, and one site is down 50% from when I installed AMP. I have it now for 7 months and no improvement.

I am using the Plumrocket extension with Magento 2.3. My plan is to disable the Plumrocket extension, and then use HTACESS to redirect all the AMP pages to my pages.

Which htaccess code should I use:

Option 1:

```
# Redirect from AMP to non-AMP page
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/amp$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Options 2:

```
// Redirect AMP to non-AMP 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/amp(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: How to install AMP on Magento 2.3.4